# ng-dirty not reset after user manually resets field?

Tags: angular

What's the reasoning behind Angular's decision to not reset an input's class from `ng-dirty` to `ng-pristine` after the user manually set a field back to its initial value?

I want to execute my save logic only if the user actually changed some of the form's data. Is there a better way than to manually hold the initial state and check for differences on submit?

Comment: Resets how?  . . .

Comment: E.g., initial value in input is `hello`, user types `a`, new input value is `helloa`, state is dirty. User presses backspace, new value is `hello` again, Angular should (imho) reset state to non-dirty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status is `dirty` this means the user changed the value. Angular doesn't track the original value though and therefore can't tell if the original value was restored.

If you want to know if the value changed, you have to store the value and on submit compare yourself if it has changed.

Comment: "The status is dirty this means the user touched the value." - isn't that what the states `ng-touched` and `ng-untouched` are for? Aren't you even implying this by saying "the user touched the value" :-)

Comment: You are right, sorry. AFAIK it still doesn't keep the original value around to compare. `ng-touched` only checks if the control had the focus.

Comment: Ok, that's really unfortunate. Do you know anything about the reasoning why they haven't included a change tracking feature? It is really cumbersome to write such logic for all my fields...a pity. I'll create a feature request.

Comment: I guess it's too complicated considering `ngModel` supports custom components with any kind of value where it's unclear what "unchanged" means. But the API could be extended so that the component has to implement the comparison itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/a/3198202/1400869 would be a reasonable comparison approach.

Comment: I created an issue at https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12213, in the meantime: thanks for elaborating the current possibilities.

Comment: Unlikely the Angular2 team will add a dependency to lodash for this.